# Accessing JSON data from AFNetworking using Swift

Tags: json, swift, afnetworking-2

I have access a Yahoo Finance data set with the link in the code.  It executes and prints the JSON data in the debug window.  How would I store and then print selected fields in myNameLabel.  For example the "symbol" or "LastTradePriceOnly" fields?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var myNameLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()

        manager.GET( "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22AAPL%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=",
            parameters: nil,
            success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!) in
                println("JSON: " + responseObject.description)

                //How to access and print individual fields?

            },
            failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error: NSError!) in
                println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
            })
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: De-serialize with the `NSJSONSerialization` class, that will result in an array or dictionary depending the the top JSON element. Then access the values from the array or dictionary with standard Swift syntax.

Comment: Take a look at AFN's Swift brother - [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire). :)

Comment: @Zaph FYI, the `responseObject` is already deserialized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just navigate the structure of nested dictionaries, perhaps something like:

```
manager.GET( "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quote%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22AAPL%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=",
    parameters: nil,
    success: {
        operation, responseObject in

        if let quote = responseObject?.objectForKey("query")?.objectForKey("results")?.objectForKey("quote") as? NSDictionary {

            let symbol = quote.objectForKey("Symbol") as? String
            let lastTradePriceOnly = quote.objectForKey("LastTradePriceOnly") as? String

            println("results: \(symbol) @ \(lastTradePriceOnly)")
        } else {
            println("no quote")
        }
    },
    failure: {
        operation, error in

        println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    })
```

Comment: @MinnesotaSteve FYI, I updated example to handle optionals (what if one of those keys were missing from the dictionary).

Comment: any suggestions on passing the APPL as the ticker var into the YQL string that is the q param value?  Seems Alamofire does not like concatenating the string as a let

Comment: Alamofire doesn't care how you build the URL string, whether literal, via concatenation, or interpolation. But I'd be inclined to use `parameters` parameter to `GET` function, regardless. But this discussion doesn't belong here in comments: post your own question.